# How to maintain the height of the title equally css

Tags: html, css

My application has a product tiles, which will have product title, product image, product price, special offers etc...,

But i stuck at one point, whenever the title of the product is big, then my tiles are distorted, i need to maintain a equal heights.

I tried a couple of css fixes but doesn't work properly. Like wise i have price, special offers too, need to maintain equal heights if one of the text is increased.

Expectation: If any of the product title, product offers etc.., text is bigger, then my UI should not be distorted.

This is what I tried:

```css
.section,
#tiles {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    zoom: 1;
}
.tileContainer {
    width: 76.5%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.tileWrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}
.tileColumn {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 239.7px;
}
.tileProduct {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 15px 20px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
.spOff {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    max-height: 80px;
}
.spOff p {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    padding-left: 7px;
}
.tileImgContainer {
    width: 160px;
    height: 220px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}
h6 {
    max-height: 75px;
    color: #000;
}
img {
    max-height: 220px;
    max-width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
   <div class="tileContainer">
      <div id="tiles">
         <div class="tileWrapper">
            <div class="tileColumn">
               <div class="tileProduct">
                  <div class="spOff">
                     <p>$1000 Off</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tileImg">
                     <div class="tileImgContainer">
                        <img src="http://i00.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/2039068830_1/All-32-teams-black-white-orange-font-b-custom-b-font-made-men-American-football-customized.jpg_220x220.jpg" />
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <h6>Loreum Ispum</h6>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="tileWrapper">
            <div class="tileColumn">
               <div class="tileProduct">
                  <div class="spOff">
                     <p>$1000 Off</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tileImg">
                     <div class="tileImgContainer">
                        <img src="http://i00.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/2039068830_1/All-32-teams-black-white-orange-font-b-custom-b-font-made-men-American-football-customized.jpg_220x220.jpg" />
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <h6>Loreum Ispum Loreum Ispum Loreum Ispum Loreum Ispum Loreum Ispum Loreum Ispum Loreum Ispum Loreum Ispum</h6>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="tileWrapper">
            <div class="tileColumn">
               <div class="tileProduct">
                  <div class="spOff">
                     <p>$1000 Off</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tileImg">
                     <div class="tileImgContainer">
                        <img src="http://i00.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/2039068830_1/All-32-teams-black-white-orange-font-b-custom-b-font-made-men-American-football-customized.jpg_220x220.jpg" />
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <h6>Loreum Ispum</h6>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="tileWrapper">
            <div class="tileColumn">
               <div class="tileProduct">
                  <div class="spOff">
                     <p>$1000 Off</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tileImg">
                     <div class="tileImgContainer">
                        <img src="http://i00.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/2039068830_1/All-32-teams-black-white-orange-font-b-custom-b-font-made-men-American-football-customized.jpg_220x220.jpg" />
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <h6>Loreum Ispum Loreum Ispum Loreum Ispum Loreum Ispum</h6>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="tileWrapper">
            <div class="tileColumn">
               <div class="tileProduct">
                  <div class="spOff">
                     <p>$1000 Off</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tileImg">
                     <div class="tileImgContainer">
                        <img src="http://i00.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/2039068830_1/All-32-teams-black-white-orange-font-b-custom-b-font-made-men-American-football-customized.jpg_220x220.jpg" />
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <h6>Loreum Ispum Loreum Ispum Loreum Ispum Loreum Ispum</h6>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="tileWrapper">
            <div class="tileColumn">
               <div class="tileProduct">
                  <div class="spOff">
                     <p>$1000 Off</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tileImg">
                     <div class="tileImgContainer">
                        <img src="http://i00.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/2039068830_1/All-32-teams-black-white-orange-font-b-custom-b-font-made-men-American-football-customized.jpg_220x220.jpg" />
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <h6>Loreum Ispum Loreum Ispum Loreum Ispum</h6>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply want to align the wrappers to the top of the line box …?

```
.tileWrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/axfocg61/

---

If that’s not it, please be more specific. An image showing what it is supposed to look like might help.

Be aware that my proposed solution fixes the alignment only – if you actually need elements to be of the same height (f.e. because a background or border should be applied to each tile), then you should look into flexbox.

Comment: My product tile has product title, special offers etc.. if the text is bigger in one tile, then the other tiles are getting screwed.  The fix which you gave worked fine for product title, but for the special offers it's not working. Please check this link.

https://jsfiddle.net/axfocg61/1/

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you mean. Where in that fiddle would that “special offer” be?

Answer (score 0):

```
.tileWrapper {
    display: block;
}

.tileWrapper:nth-child(5n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Blindshot.

For equal heights, try adding a fixed `height` and `overflow-y: hidden` to `.tileProduct`.